# HP System Event Utility update not showing

Tags: updates, hp

I found that HP recommends to update HP System Event Utility due to a vulnerability. I did this (after virustotal scans) using their recommendation: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06559359

This was all fine, windows defender also found no issues, but under Apps & Features, the old version is still showing, and in control panel no program of that name is even listed (Nor was it before I installed the update). Any help understanding and resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Three things to try that worked for me:

1. (at least on my HP) Just deleting the app seems to have had no effect and removes the need for an update.
2. The last commentin this thread (https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/HP-System-Event-Utility-not-working-Mainly-the-Omen-button/td-p/7928263) has the link to the microsoft store app, which should correctly install.
3. Open the file location and run the windows installer, it should then update.

Comment: Even from the hpsupport link, the UWP version is downloaded, so it should only appear in Apps & Features, not in control panel.